# Why popup windows are blocked by popup blocker when i am not logged in to my vbulletin forum?

Tags: php, javascript, popup-blocker

I am using a vBulletin forum for my website and I am designing an application.
In my application, javascript opens a popup window using **window.open()** javascript method.
I have to open the popup at this point in my application because i don't want to loose the currently loaded webpage. When I am logged into my forum, everything works perfect.

But when i am not logged into my forum the javascript does not open the popup window when **window.open()** is executed. The **popup blocker** blocks the popup from opening everytime i try to execute the JavaScript code.

Why the browser does not block popups when i am logged into my forum? 
What is the difference between these two states where popup blocker does not work them same way?
Is there any code or trick available to bypass the popup blocker at the time of opening the popup?

Please guide me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The popup blocker is generally triggered when a `window.open()` call happens in the wrong kind of event loop.  When exactly do you open the window?  That is, what triggers it?  If it's a "click", it should be OK, but you can't do it (for example) on page load, or in response to an XMLHttpRequest completion.

Comment: @Pointy:Thank you. That really helped. I was calling the window.open() method on XMLHttpRequest completion.